# How do you handle having hundreds of console workers?

Tags: console-application, devops, orchestration

I am having trouble handling hundreds of console workers across different servers.
Defining a worker: It's a simple console app that processes some data and repeats its job infinitely.

But what to do when you have hundreds of console workers?
How do you manage them or check them if they are running?

Is there any term for this specific process or any kind of orchestration?

Comment: Well, you could monitor them using one of the [many monitoring systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems) ( [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) + [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) can be a good combination, [Icinga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icinga) is also nice ).